# Formatting rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table where data is as follows:

```
Id  displayorder    DisplayName ColumnName  ColumnValue
596 7   Current Status  CURRENTSTATUS   OBS1
596 7   Current Status  CURRENTSTATUS   OBS2
594 5   Description DESCRIPTION PCBA,TD LTE 2500,MHUB
594 5   Description DESCRIPTION RAD II MTG BRKT, HORZ
593 4   Name    NAME    1225857
593 4   Name    NAME    1323106
599 12  Type    TYPE    Assemblies, General
599 12  Type    TYPE    Assembly Drawing
```

What I need to do is. Change the above format into the following format.

```
Id  displayorder    DisplayName ColumnName  ColumnValue
596 7   Current Status  CURRENTSTATUS   OBS1
594 5   Description DESCRIPTION RAD II MTG BRKT, HORZ
593 4   Name    NAME    1323106
599 12  Type    TYPE    Assembly Drawing
596 7   Current Status  CURRENTSTATUS   OBS2
594 5   Description DESCRIPTION PCBA,TD LTE 2500,MHUB
593 4   Name    NAME    1225857
599 12  Type    TYPE    Assemblies, General
```

It is a hash table and four rows with different ids represent 1 row. For example, ids 596 to 599 represents one row.

Please help!

Comment: You probably have to parse it first, then your solution will be obvious.

Comment: can you please elaborate :)

Comment: You've said: " ids 596 to 599 represents one row", but you want to see them as 4 rows. Right?

Comment: No. They represents 4 columns of a row. Column names are under "ColumnName" column and their corresponding values are under column "ColumnValue". Please see the format in which I want the table to be formatted. :)

Comment: You should definitely format that result table in a way that makes it **CLEAR** what you want - right now, it's anything *but* clear.....

Comment: Your comment  " ids 596 to 599 represents one row" is very confusing then. I can't interpret it. <BR/>

Comment: use row_number()over(partition by id order by (select null)).even order by is not clear.

Comment: This is called EAV. You can read more about it here: [What is so bad about EAV, anyway?](https://sqlblog.org/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ROW_NUMBER + ordering:

```
SELECT  Id, 
        displayorder, 
        DisplayName, 
        ColumnName, 
        ColumnValue
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DisplayName ORDER BY displayorder, ColumnValue) rn
    FROM YourTableName
) as p
ORDER BY rn, DisplayName
```

Output:

```
Id          displayorder DisplayName    ColumnName                  ColumnValue
----------- ------------ -------------- --------------------------- -------------------
596         7            Current Status CURRENTSTATUS               OBS1
594         5            Description    DESCRIPTION RAD II MTG BRKT HORZ
593         4            Name           NAME                        1225857
599         12           Type           TYPE                        Assemblies, General
596         7            Current Status CURRENTSTATUS               OBS2
594         5            Description    DESCRIPTION  PCBA,TD        LTE 2500,MHUB
593         4            Name           NAME                        1323106
599         12           Type           TYPE                        Assembly Drawing
```